# python - get time in specific format

Tags: python, time

I need to get time in format: hour:minutes:seconds. But if I use:

```
 time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(my_time))) #my_time is float
```

hour have a 24-hour clock (00 to 23). And when I have for example 25 hour and 2 minutes, it writes 1:02:00, but I need 25:02:00. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: _25:02:00_ is **not** a time.

Comment: how is it possible to get 25:02:00 when you use `time.gmtime`?

Comment: The OP is talking about *elapsed time*, not time of day here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `time.strftime()` to format elapsed time. You can only format a time of day value with that; the two types of values are related but not the same thing.

You'll need to use custom formatting instead.

If `my_time` is elapsed time in seconds, you can use the following function to format it to a *hours:minutes:seconds* format:

```
def format_elapsed_time(seconds):
    seconds = int(seconds + 0.5)  # round to nearest second
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def format_elapsed_time(seconds):
...     seconds = int(seconds + 0.5)  # round to nearest second
...     minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
...     hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
...     return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
... 
>>> format_elapsed_time(90381.33)
'25:06:21'
```

Comment: use `seconds = int(seconds + .5)` to avoid `ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'`

Comment: Ah I missed the comment stating the value is a float.